# $\sigma$-algebra for a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A sample problem is the following:
The lifetime of a certain kind of TV tube is a continuous Random Variable with Probability Distribution Function (PDF):
\begin{equation*}
f(x) =  \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad x \leq 100 \\
            \frac{100}{x^2} & \quad x > 100
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}
It's clear that the Sample space is $\mathbb{R}^+$. But I have no clue as to what the $\sigma$-algebra is here.

**P.S.**: I'm a first year undergrad student, so it will be better if people whoever is answering please explain their notations. Also, I asked this just out of curiosity and is probably not a part of our coursework.

Comment: In general for continuous RVs (in $\mathbb{R}$) it is sufficient with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sigma algebra should include all the questions you could logically ask about the variable that are measurable. In this case, you are interested in possible values of the lifetime of a TV tube.

If $f(x) = \frac{100}{x^2}\;\;x>100$  we have

$$P(X<x) = \int_{100}^x \frac{100}{x^2}dx = 1-\frac{100}{x}$$

So we have our probability measure over intervals. This measure is defined over all open intervals of $\mathbb{R}\setminus (-\infty,100]$ so the applicable $\sigma-$algebra would be:

$$\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\setminus (-\infty,100]\right)$$

This is the Borel sigma algebra, as mentoined in the comments by @matias Vera.

Comment: can you mention/recommend some resources where I can learn more about Borel algebra ? (It will be better if it starts from scratch) - @Bey